# What's different between Task.Run(job) and job(); await Task.CompleteTask?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, async-await

I want to make a sync function to async

```cs
public JobSync()
{
 // a lot of logic
}
```

both

```cs
public async JobAsync()
{
 JobSync()
 await Task.CompleteTask;
}
```

and

```
Task.Run(()=>JobSync())
```

works,

but is there any difference between two ways?

Comment: First will run on same thread, second will create new thread to run given method.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I want to make a sync function to async

This version is not asynchronous at all:

```
public async Task JobAsync()
{
    JobSync()
    await Task.CompleteTask;
}
```

It will run completely synchronously, and your simply adding unnecessary overhead through the `async` keyword.

This version is "fake async":

```
Task.Run(()=>JobSync())
```

`Task.Run` simply runs the synchronous code on the thread-pool. It does, however, return a `Task` before `JobSync` is ran, which can be useful if your targeting a UI app, as the UI thread is released while `JobSync` runs.

The real question here is *why* you want to make `JobSync` asynchronous, and the answer is you shouldn't.

Async comes into its own when the method involves I/O, as the thread can be released to process other work whilst waiting for the response.

If `JobSync` is an expensive CPU-bound method that is freezing your UI, simply call it using `Task.Run`:

```
await Task.Run(JobSync);
```

---

**Update as per comment**

If you are targeting an API that requires a `Task`-returning method, such as `BackgroundService.ExecuteAsync`, then `Task.FromResult` is the most efficient workaround:

```
public override Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken ct)
{
    return Task.FromResult(JobSync());
}
```

This simply raps the result of `JobSync()` in a `Task` object to satisfy the requirement of `ExecuteAsync`, but does not force the code to run on the ThreadPool unnecessarily.

Comment: Thanks, I am using it to fit `BackgroundService`. `ExecuteAsync` method, I mean sometimes    the method signature needs param to be async or need return Task

Comment: It does, and that's way there is `Task.FromResult` See update above.

Comment: does it mean `Task.FromResult` will make `JobSync()` run on a dedicated thread or current thread?

Comment: @Panic `Task.FromResult` is also a synchronous method, it just creates a `Task` object, in a completed state, and sets it's `Result` property. No thread switching occurs, and that is exactly what you want, considering it is already running in the background.